# validate two fields with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery Validate Plugin: 
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

**Simple demo:**

```
  <input type="text" name="email" class="required email" />
  <input type="text" name="email_confirm" class="required email" />
```

How to check if the value in the two inputs are the same with jQuery or with jQuery Validate Plugin.

I just tried `equalto` and it works:

```
rules: {
  email: 'required',
  email2: {equalTo: '.email'}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By looking at the demo page at  http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ you can validate 2 fields that should be equal by using "equalTo":

```
    $("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
                    ...snip... 
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
                   ...snip...
    },
    messages: {
        ...snip...
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        },
        ...snip...
    }
});
```

To do it using the class method, you just need to find the syntax.  I couldn't find it for the equalTo attribute, but it is probably something like:

```
class="required email equalTo['email']"
```

Comment: Great!  If you found this answer to be the correct one, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark to the left of it.  Thanks

Comment: thanks was looking for the class equivalent... oops should test unless someone has confirmed?

Comment: The class equivalent doesn't seem to work, but we can use the attribute equalTo, for example
<input id="confirm_password" name="password" equalTo="#password" />
Source:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/validate-apply-equalto-rule-inline-to-input-class